# How to consume Kafka-events with spring-cloud-function, but only sometimes produce

Tags: kotlin, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have successfully set up spring-cloud-function with kafka-streams in Kotlin and have a working prototype.

I have one function that receives the events from one topic and produces another event to another topic.

Here's my `application.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        consumeAndProduce-in-0:
          destination: topicToConsumeFrom
        consumeAndProduce-out-0:
          destination: topicToProduceTo
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka.broker.prod}
      default:
        group: ${spring.application.name}
    function:
      definition: consumeAndProduce
```

My kotlin application looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class Application {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<Application>(*args)
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun consumeAndProduce(): (ConsumerEvent) -> ProducerEvent {
        return { message ->
            doSomethingAndReturnProducerEvent(message)
        }
    }
}
```

I followed numerous examples on the internet and it works like a charm. As soon as a message is put into the `topicToConsumeFrom`, the function is called and the result will be written to the `topicToProduceTo`.

---

**Now my question:**
What would be the proper handling if my function is *not always* producing something. It is a very common use-case that a service listens on a topic and ignores messages. It should only react to specific messages and only then produce an output, otherwise do nothing. I tried that by creating a different producer function, which I call from the consumer only if applicable:

Here's my adapted `application.yml` that now defines two different functions `consume`and `produce`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        consume-in-0:
          destination: topicToConsumeFrom
        produce-out-0:
          destination: topicToProduceTo
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka.broker.prod}
      default:
        group: ${spring.application.name}
    function:
      definition: consume;produce
```

In my application, I renamed `consumeAndProduce()`to `consume()` and the return value is now `Unit`. Also, I created a second bean `produce()` that does nothing but returning a function that returns the payload that I give to it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class Application {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<Application>(*args)
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun consume(produce: (ProducerEvent) -> ProducerEvent): (ConsumerEvent) -> Unit {
        return { message ->
            if (isSomethingIWantToReactTo(message)) {
                val result = doSomethingAndReturnProduceEvent(message)
                producer(result)
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun produce(): (ProducerEvent) -> ProducerEvent {
        return { it }
    }
}
```

Now the `consume()`-function is called if a message is present in the topic and if the message is for me, I'll do something and call the `produce()`-function with my result, otherwise do nothing.

I was not able to see any message in the outgoing topic.
I know through debugging, that it went into the if-branch and calls `produce()` with my result, but it seems the kafka-binding doesn't work and no message is ever really sent.

I'm aware, my approach is somewhat naïve, but after extensive research I couldn't find anything that describes this use-case. All examples always have *one* function that consumes and produces in all cases.

Is there a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions based on the first code example using only one function `consumeAndProduce()` for consuming and producing:

1. Return a nullable event. If the function returns `null`, no event will be produced:

```
@Bean
fun consumeAndProduce(): (ConsumerEvent) -> ProducerEvent? {
    return { message ->
        if(isSomethingIWantToReactTo(message)) {
            doSomethingAndReturnProducerEvent(message)
        }
        null
    }
}
```

2. Use `KStream`s to consume a stream of events and produce a stream of events. That way any incoming event that does not apply can simply be filtered:

```
@Bean
fun consumeAndProduce(): (KStream<ConsumerEvent>) -> KStream<ProducerEvent> {
    return { messages ->
        messages
            .filter(message -> isSomethingIWantToReactTo(message))
            .map(message -> doSomethingAndReturnProducerEvent(message))
    }
}
```

**Note:** I did not follow this approach and didn't try it out, thus research into KStreams is advised.